# Can 'mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification' dirty the context being merged to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two contexts and I'm merging from one to the other.
I have a one-to-one Object relationship.
E.g:

```
NSManagedObject *one;
NSManagedObject *two;
one.rel = two;
```

When I'm merging my notification.userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] has:
[one, two]

When I call [context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

The context now has "two" in it the updatedObjects property.  I can see this happening when I walk over the instruction.

Is this even possible? I was under the impression [context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification] shouldn't dirty the context?

Comment: Was "two" related to "one" in the context you merged into before the merge?

Comment: @Avi No it shouldn't be, but lets assume it might or might not be.

Comment: If you create a new relationship in the merged-into context, it makes sense that it would be dirty after the merge.  I am not sure why you are surprised.

Comment: @Avi The relationship was made before the merge. The main context would still be dirty after the merge?